# Como fazer um filtro através de atributo em um objeto / array

Tags: javascript, jquery

acredito que seja uma dúvida simples mas não estou encontrando uma solução para o meu problema.

Exemplo:

Objeto:

```
{projectId:"1" name:"Projeto A" image:"imagem.jpg"}
{projectId:"2" name:"Projeto B" image:"imagem.jpg"}
{projectId:"3" name:"Projeto C" image:"imagem.jpg"}
{projectId:"4" name:"Projeto D" image:"imagem.jpg"}
{projectId:"5" name:"Projeto E" image:"imagem.jpg"}
```

Eu tenho um menu no qual eu já estou pegando o valor da id e gostaria de fazer um busca neste objeto atrav[es deste id para carregar a imagem correta.

```
$('.btn').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $id = ($(this).attr("id"));   
    }
  })
```

Desde já muito obrigado :)

Comment: A qual propriedade desse objeto corresponde o ID? queres filtrar para encontrar só um ou alguns dentro dessa array?

Comment: você pode utilizar a propriedade filter do array

Comment: Isso, conforme o valor que vier no $id, eu quero filtrar essa array e identificar a qual nó ela pertence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se queres encontrar 1 elemento então deves usar o `.find()`:

```
$('.btn').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      const id = this.id;  
      const el = arr.find(obj => obj.projectId == id); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Sempre temos a aprender contigo, hein. Boa resposta.

Comment: Funcionou de primeira, muito obrigado... obrigado a todos, não cheguei a testar todas as formas de resolver, mas acredito que todas são ótimas alternativas.

Comment: @FernandoDiasMotta Você pode marcar a resposta que mais te ajudou como correta. É só usar o **V** do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Comment: @FernandoDiasMotta se queres só um elemento o `.find()` é o mais correto de usar. Há sempre várias maneiras, que são adaptações de ferramentas feitas para outras coisas.

Answer (score 5):

É possível usar a função [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro). Ela recebe como parâmetro um *callback* que vai validar cada item da sua coleção.

Algo como

```
mouseenter: function () {
    $id = ($(this).attr("id"));
    const filtrado = arr.filter(item => item.projectId == $id);
}
```

Veja funcionando.

```js
const arr = [{ projectId:"1", name:"Projeto A", image:"imagem.jpg" },
{projectId:"2", name:"Projeto B", image:"imagem.jpg"},
{projectId:"3", name:"Projeto C", image:"imagem.jpg"},
{projectId:"4", name:"Projeto D", image:"imagem.jpg"},
{projectId:"5", name:"Projeto E", image:"imagem.jpg"}];

const id = 1; // <- Aqui seria a variável que você captura no evento 

const filtrado = arr.filter(item => item.projectId == id);

console.log(filtrado);
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você deve usar o `jQuery.grep()`:

```
var found_names = $.grep(names, function(v) {
    return v.projectId === 1;
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var names = [];

var object = {projectId:"1", name:"Projeto A", image:"imagem.jpg"};
names.push(object);

object = {projectId:"2", name:"Projeto B", image:"imagem.jpg"};
names.push(object);

var found_names = $.grep(names, function(v) {
    return v.projectId === "1";
});

console.log(found_names);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Basta olhar o console do seu navegador.

Comment: Sempre temos a aprender contigo, hein. Boa resposta.